# Cordova iOS - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm new to Cordova and am trying to create an app that will pass a variable from the bootstrap-slider to another function, where it will be sent using BLE.  I'm passing the variable to my testSend function, but am getting the error: "unrecognized selector sent to instance" at that point.

First my slider receives a value from the user, which works fine...

```
    var slider = new Slider('#ex1', {
        formatter: function(value) {
            return 'Current value: ' + value;

        },
        tooltip: 'always'
    });


    slider.on('slideStop', function(value) {
        document.getElementById('sliderDiv').innerHTML = value;
console.log(value);
```

...the value shows up fine in the console log, so then I try passing the value to my testSend function...

```
       testSend(value);
    });
```

... I get the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance ". What causes this error and how do I go about fixing it?

```
function testSend(xVar){



 data= stringToBytes(xVar);

 var success = function() {
 console.log("success");
 resultDiv.innerHTML = resultDiv.innerHTML + "Sent: " + messageInput.value + "<br/>";
 resultDiv.scrollTop = resultDiv.scrollHeight;
};

 var failure = function() {
 alert("Failed writing data to the bluefruit le");
 };

 var deviceId = event.target.dataset.deviceId;

 if (app.writeWithoutResponse) {
 ble.writeWithoutResponse(
     deviceId,
     bluefruit.serviceUUID,
     bluefruit.txCharacteristic,
     data, success, failure
 );
 } else {
 ble.write(
     deviceId,
     bluefruit.serviceUUID,
     bluefruit.txCharacteristic,
     data, success, failure
 );
 }
}
```